# hPlot R x-axis label and x-y correspondence

Tags: r, rcharts

I have the following data and trying to plot using `hPlot`

```
hPlot(Numbers~Date, data = df, group='Type', type = "line", radius=6)


     Date        Type      Numbers
 2014-01-05     Type-1          16
 2014-01-12     Type-1          82
 2014-01-12     Type-2           2
 2014-01-19     Type-1         177
 2014-01-26     Type-1         270
 2014-01-26     Type-2           3
 2014-02-02     Type-1         381
 2014-02-09     Type-1         461
 2014-02-09     Type-2           4
```

I am getting multiple dates as x-axis as shown in figure below. I also tried `unique` and `as.character` but the x-data is not corresponding to y-data.

[image]

Comment: You don't have an element named `Week` in your data.frame. Does `df$Week <- format(df$Date, '%U'); hPlot(Numbers~Week, data = df, group='Type', type = "line", radius=6)` get closer to what you want?

Comment: Is `Date` actually a date object? Try `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%Y-%m-%d')`.

Comment: Its a date object. I also tried changing it to character. There are Type-1 values for all dates, but not Type-2 values, so for Type-2 its plotting dots for first three weeks not corresponding weeks.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(df)` so that we have the same data frame you are working with?

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(16075, 16082, 16082, 16089, 
16096, 16096, 16103, 16110, 16110), class = "Date"), Type = c("Type-1", 
"Type-1", "Type-2", "Type-1", "Type-1", "Type-2", "Type-1", "Type-1", 
"Type-2"), Numbers = c(16, 82, 2, 177, 270, 3, 381, 461, 4)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Type", "Numbers"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Is this the bug in hPlot/rHighcharts

Comment: @Ramnath, Could you please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem. You can view the chart along with code [here](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?9301903). I am posting it here as well

```
# don't switch to scientific notation, since we want date to be
# represented in milliseconds
options(scipen = 13)
dat = transform(df, Date2 = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Date))*1000)

library(rCharts)
h1 <- hPlot(Numbers ~ Date2, data = dat, 
  group = 'Type', 
  type = "line", 
  radius=6
)
h1$xAxis(type = 'datetime', labels = list(
  format = '{value:%Y-%m-%d}'  
))
h1
```